# How do I use driver from Universal directory in a UEFI_APPLICATION

Tags: driver, uefi, edk2

I want to use some of the functions provided by the PartitionDxe, but I do not understand how to use this driver within my application as it does not have GUID in any header files. What do I need to include in the inf/dsc and how can I use it after it is linked to my application?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

PartitionDxe is a driver and not a library.

It provides access to the logical partitions based on the disk layout (Gpt, Mbr,...), to do that it creates new instances of BlockIo(2), DiskIo(2) and PartitionInformation protocols.
If you need some of its functions you have to copy it from the source code files.

Comment: Is there not a standard way to use driver's functions via a 'protocol'?

Comment: Yes, but the PartitionDxe driver has no "own" protocol, it uses the existing BlockIo,... protocols to allow the system access to the logical partitions.

Comment: Can I implement a protocol for the driver myself?

Comment: You could implement your own PartitionsUtilsDxe, but if you need just some methods from the driver the easiest way would be to copy them from the drivers source code and create your own library.